# MongoDB Updating to nested array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a  mongoose schema as

```
 image: 
  {
    imageVisibility: 
    {
        type:Number,default:1
    },
    profileImage: {
      imageUrl: String,
      status: Boolean
    },
    otherImages: [
      {
        imageUrl: String,
        status: Boolean
      }
    ]
  }
```

At first OtherImages array will be null during singup and later on while updating the  OtherImages using query 
`db.userdetails.update({},{$set: {'image.otherImages.imageUrl':'bharat.jpg'}})` 
show the error

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 28,
            "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'imageUrl' in element {otherImages: []}"
    }
```

})

Is  there any  thing missing , sorry i  am new  to  the mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

After going through  the doc what i  found missing is placing an index  for array update 
Here is my answer to  the question

```
     db.userdetails.update({}, 
   { $set: { "image.otherImages.0.imageUrl" : "bharat.jpg"}
 })
```